# Abbreviation of if statement options in shell

Tags: shell

There is some if statement options in shell script.
For example `-d` for directory `-f` for file.

My question is what does stand for `-n` and `-z` options?
I know how it works. I want to know etymology to assist memory the options.
And where can I find `man` for it?

Comment: And while you're reading the `test` manpage, before the `[ ]` expressions in the shell were introduced, the statements looked like `if test -z "$var" ; then ...`. Somewhat later you found a link `/bin/test => /bin/[` and you could write that as `if [ -z "$var" ] ; then ...`. So you still can't write `[-z ...`, you always need a blank after the `[`.

Comment: So, there is a historical reason. Thanks! Your comment is very informative!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Lookup `man test` for information on if (or test as the if utility is known in Linux)

`-z` string     True if the length of string is **Z**ero.

`-n` string     True if the length of string is *N*onzero

Comment: Glad it was of use.

Answer (score 0):

Look at the `test` command in the man pages.  This will give you an idea as to the flags that can be used in the shell "internal and abbreviated" test calls.

I believe that at one time the `test` commands were not built-in to many of the shells and thus this was the command you had to use in shell `if` statements.  But that was a long time ago.

Answer (score 0):

```
$ man-section bash
bash (1)
----
      Name
      Synopsis
      Copyright
      Description
      Options
      Arguments
      Invocation
      Definitions
      Reserved words
      Shell grammar
      Comments
      Quoting
      Parameters
      Expansion
      Redirection
      Aliases
      Functions
      Arithmetic evaluation
 -->  Conditional expressions
```

(...)

```
$ man bash |grep -Ee '-[nz].*string' -A1 -m2
       -z string
          True if the length of string is zero.
--
       -n string
          True if the length of string is non-zero.
```

Comment: I'm using Ubuntu 12.04, and could not find `man-section` command neither build-in nor `apt-cache search`. How to get the `man-section` command? The way using pipe and grep works fine! I need learn more grep options though. Thanks!

Comment: man-section: http://sprunge.us/geVK